# Remote Switch wiring for a gas log fire place

Tags: wiring, fireplace

I have a remote switch outside my gas log fireplace to turn the fireplace  burner on and off. I've been having problems with the standard thermostat wiring that was supplied with my remote switch. The wiring is melting. Should I be using a "heat resistant" wiring to run from my wall switch thru my fire place to control the ignition of the burners?  The answer seem obviously "yes" but do you have a recommended type of wire for this application?

Again the wall switch simply "jumpers" two terminals on my gas valve, thus allowing the gas valve to open and thus the burners to ignite off the pilot. I was thinking of going to my local electrical supply house for some "heat/temperature" resistant low voltage capable wiring and trying that. Also should I run that wiring under the burner pan or behind the burner pan and under the sand/stones provided for aesthetics for the fire place?  .

Comment: The wires shouldn't be close enough to the flame to melt.

Answer (score 1):

I thought any time you came within 18" of a stove or insert (fireplace type) you were supposed to use "glass" or high temp appliance wire (but this may be an Oregon thing).  It is about a buck a foot here in the pacific northwest. You only need a small gauge to control your gas valve; 18 would probably do just fine but it may be easier to find 14awg.  The wire I am talking about has a glass braid on the outside and some type of plastic inner insulation, this type of wire can handle the heat unlike standard AWM/NM/THHN. Plumbing and electric stores usually have it; I'm not sure about the big box stores.

Comment: Wow not sure what happened there , but when I typed Romex maybe I should have said NM , as that is in 99% of all house wiring nothing else I had changed a few things , it doubled everything don't have a better answer ? Humm